# 三目並べ、三つの盤面で同時、✖のみ使用　先手の必勝法を考える

Tags: アルゴリズム

このゲームでは先手に必勝法がある。参照Youtube：Numberphile 3 board tic tac toe
ただし、プログラミングに落とし込むぐらいの簡単な必勝法がみつからない。
目標はその必勝法を利用して疑似AIを作ること。

ルール：
このゲームの盤面は基本的に三つの三目ならべのボードで構成されている
参加者二名が使う印は”X”で共通
ひとりずつ任意の格子に印をつける
三つ印がつながったらそのボードだけ消える。
最後に残ったボード（場面）で、三つXをならべてしまった参加者が負ける

ボード一つの場合は先手が真ん中に駒をおけば簡単にかてるが、ボード三つだと難しい。

Comment: 「三つ印がつながったらその盤面のみ消える」がよくわかりませんでした。「盤面」は基本的に全体をさす言葉でここでいうと「三つの印の列やかたまり」をさしますか？

Comment: ＠keitaro_so      編集しました。もう一度確認してください

Comment: 二人とも×しか使わないならどう見分けるのか、一般的には「先に揃えたら勝ち」だが「三つ×を並べてしまったら負け」とは？三つのボードじゃなくて、まず一つのボードから考えてみたらどうか / 現状だと (独自の) ルールが書かれているだけで、解決にあたって何に困っているのかが不明瞭に感じます。「必勝法がある」のに「見つからない」というのも矛盾していますし。

Comment: 「みつからない」だけではなくて、今までに考えてうまくいかなかったことを質問文に書いていただけると回答しやすそうです。個人的には、ルールはこれで充分わかりやすいなと感じました。

Comment: @cubick  矛盾していません。このゲームはNumberphile にも登場しているゲームで、必勝法はあるらしいんですがそれをプログラミングに落とし込むのは難しいから「見つからない」という表現をしています

Comment: 回答間違ってたので消しておきました

Answer (score 0):

まずはご自身で何回か手を動かし、このゲームを実際にプレイしてみてください。すると規則性が見えてくるかなと思います。

このゲームは、ゲームの最中に取り得る場面の状態を列挙できます。27 マスのそれぞれに印がついているかついていないかなので高々 2^27 通りで、ゲームのルールや対称性を気にすると更に減ります（ひとつの盤面に置ける印の数は最大いくつでしょうか）。またこのゲームにはランダム要素が一切なく、ゲームをするにあたって必要な情報は全て全員に公開されています。

したがって、今どの状態にいるかが分かると、次どの状態になれば最適なのかが必ず分かります。最初に全部探索して覚えておいて、今いる状態から望ましい状態に向けて次の手を選べば良いです。

もしこれで計算時間が長くなりすぎてしまうのであれば、ミニマックス法やアルファ・ベータ法などの有名な枝刈り法が役に立つでしょう。

Comment: このゲームは誰が先に駒を置いたのも考えなくてはならないので、２＊＊２７通りより多いと思います。計算時間が長いのは当たり前ですが、メモリーもかなりつかいそうです。２＊＊２７通りだとしても軽々百万超えてて、将棋AIよりも多くの手を読まなきゃいけない事になりますよ。
もし具体的にどうやって答えを絞るのかを考えて頂ければ有難いです。

Comment: いえ、「誰が先に駒を置いたか」は場面の状態ではありません。それを含めるとしたらゲームの状態です。ゲーム木のノードを組むにあたって必要な情報ではないですね。おそらく状態の持ち方を勘違いなさっているのではないかと思います。将棋 AI の状態数よりかなり少ないです。